# Can an element of a group be its own inverse?

Tags: group-theory

A set S={0,1} is to prove a group with respect to addition modulo.  In satisfying group's property i stuck in the in the statement whether a element  itself could be an inverse ..so need a guidance . I just started to learn abstract algebra.

Comment: yes, you have $1+1=0$ in this group

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please make sure to include all information needed into your answer (e.g. "property i") and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Notice, it can even happen that all elements of a group are their own inverse (you may find interesting to prove the group is then necessarily commutative, it's a classic exercise).

Comment: Like the other's say, this is possible. If you just started to learn abstract algebra, try if you can find examples in the dihedral groups; cyclic groups of even order; general linear groups; multiplicative groups of rationals, reals, complex numbers, quaternions; and symmetric groups. You can find examples in all these groups. I assume you already learnt about these. Even the simplest example is the identity element itself (trivially).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an element $x$ of a group can be its own inverse. This happens when $x^2=e$.